# Expatriates Badge Ranking List

Tags: discussion, badges, fun

In a fun attempt to try to add some competition other than just rep, let's look at the number of [badges earned on the site](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/badges).

I'll list some of the higher ones, but feel free to add / update rankings - I'll make it an editable answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
+-------+--------------+------+--------+--------+
| Rank  |    User      | Gold | Silver | Bronze |
+-------+--------------+------+--------+--------+
|   1   | Sztupy       |  4   |  22    |   57   |   
|   2   | Mark Mayo    |  4   |  18    |   79   |   
|   3   | Gala         |  2   |  15    |   51   |
|   4   | StrongBad    |  2   |  10    |   40   | 
|   5   | phoog        |  2   |   6    |   24   |   
|   6   | Dorothy      |  1   |   5    |   50   |   
|   7   | user102008   |  1   |   4    |   16   |   
|   8   | Karlson      |  0   |  11    |   41   |     
|   9   | littleadv    |  0   |  11    |   31   |   
|  10   | Dipen Shah   |  0   |   6    |   22   |   
|  11   | Greg Hewgill |  0   |   4    |   17   |
+-------+--------------+------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: And with this comment, I just got another bronze badge on the Meta!

Comment: I need to work on my Bronze library

Comment: *Polishes off the shiny new Steward badge... "